# failed to build one page NextJs App in DigitalOcean

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, deployment, digital-ocean

## Update.. I moved the app to Vercel instead of DigitalOcean and It works fine.

### "*Vercel is not requiring a build file before deploying the app if it's NextJs App, Vercel will create the build files and deploy the app without any configurations* "

"

**Can someone help me understand where is the problem.**

**I'm a new programmer and this my first time working with NextJs.
I've create a one page website and I'm trying to deploying it using digitalocean but it keeps giving me this error: "ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1"**

```
[2023-02-05 15:01:31] ╭──────────── git repo clone ───────────╼
[2023-02-05 15:01:31] │  › fetching app source code
[2023-02-05 15:01:31] │ => Selecting branch "prod"
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ => Checking out commit "dda440fddc95f99345f3520f51872634dc298a02"
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │  ✔ cloned repo to /workspace
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] ╰────────────────────────────────────────╼
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] 
[2023-02-05 15:01:33]  › configuring custom build command to be run at the end of the build:
[2023-02-05 15:01:33]    │ npm run export
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] 
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] ╭──────────── buildpack detection ───────────╼
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │  › using Ubuntu 18.04 stack
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ Detected the following buildpacks suitable to build your app:
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │    heroku/nodejs-engine   v0.5.1  
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │    digitalocean/node      v0.3.4  (Node.js)
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │    digitalocean/procfile  v0.0.3  (Procfile)
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │    digitalocean/custom    v0.1.1  (Custom Build Command)
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │    Node.js  v0.3.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────╼
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] 
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] ╭──────────── app build ───────────╼
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ ---> Node.js Buildpack
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ ---> Installing toolbox
[2023-02-05 15:01:33] │ ---> - jq
[2023-02-05 15:01:34] │ ---> - yj
[2023-02-05 15:01:34] │ ---> Getting Node version
[2023-02-05 15:01:34] │ ---> Resolving Node version
[2023-02-05 15:01:35] │ ---> Downloading and extracting Node v16.19.0
[2023-02-05 15:01:39] │ ---> Parsing package.json
[2023-02-05 15:01:39] │ ---> No file to start server
[2023-02-05 15:01:39] │ ---> either use 'docker run' to start container or add index.js or server.js
[2023-02-05 15:01:39] │ Project contains package-lock.json, using npm
[2023-02-05 15:01:40] │ Found npm version range "~1.0.20" in package.json->engines.npm
[2023-02-05 15:01:40] │ Installing npm "~1.0.20"
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ npm ERR! code ETARGET
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for npm@~1.0.20.
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ npm ERR!     /home/apps/.npm/_logs/2023-02-05T15_01_41_127Z-debug-0.log
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ unable to invoke layer creator
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ installing npm: exit status 1
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │    Node.js  v0.3.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │ 
[2023-02-05 15:01:41] │  ✘ build failed
[]
```

**In the editor I followed the instruction on this link [app-nextjs-deploy]**(https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-nextjs-deploy/) a**nd when I run the npm run build it run succsusfuly.
This is the return:**

```
/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev (prod)~$ npm run build

> 3dot@0.1.0 build /Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev
> next build

info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/12)next-translate - compiled page: /about-us - locale: ar - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: /about-us - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: / - locale: ar - namespaces: common, hero, contact, footer, ourWork, services, header, overview, projects - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: / - locale: en - namespaces: common, hero, contact, footer, ourWork, services, header, overview, projects - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: /projectPreview - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: /projectPreview - locale: ar - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
info  - Generating static pages (12/12)
info  - Finalizing page optimization  

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ● /                                      502 B          99.5 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B              99 kB 
├ ○ /404                                   182 B          99.1 kB
├ ● /about-us                              1.1 kB          100 kB
└ ● /projectPreview                        751 B          99.7 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              104 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-ab06527bed40be7f.js   45.4 kB
  ├ chunks/main-a091f637108a345e.js        27 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-35010f633d6867e6.js  24.5 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-82c27b893a0dceeb.js     2.07 kB
  └ css/6192469adf69fe6c.css               4.83 kB

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
```

**And when I continue and run "npm run export" to show me the "_static" file, an error will show in the editor console :**

```
/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev (prod)~$ npm run export

> 3dot@0.1.0 export /Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev
> npm run build && next export -o _static


> 3dot@0.1.0 build /Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev
> next build

info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/12)next-translate - compiled page: / - locale: en - namespaces: common, hero, contact, footer, ourWork, services, header, overview, projects - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: /projectPreview - locale: ar - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: /projectPreview - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: /about-us - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: / - locale: ar - namespaces: common, hero, contact, footer, ourWork, services, header, overview, projects - used loader: getStaticProps
next-translate - compiled page: /about-us - locale: ar - namespaces: common - used loader: getStaticProps
info  - Generating static pages (12/12)
info  - Finalizing page optimization  

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ● /                                      502 B          99.5 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B              99 kB
├ ○ /404                                   182 B          99.1 kB
├ ● /about-us                              1.1 kB          100 kB
└ ● /projectPreview                        751 B          99.7 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              104 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-ab06527bed40be7f.js   45.4 kB
  ├ chunks/main-a091f637108a345e.js        27 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-35010f633d6867e6.js  24.5 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-82c27b893a0dceeb.js     2.07 kB
  └ css/6192469adf69fe6c.css               4.83 kB

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)

info  - using build directory: /Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev/.next
info  - Copying "static build" directory
info  - No "exportPathMap" found in "/Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev/next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"
Error: i18n support is not compatible with next export. See here for more info on deploying: https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment
    at /Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:147:19
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! 3dot@0.1.0 export: `npm run build && next export -o _static`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the 3dot@0.1.0 export script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/baraa/.npm/_logs/2023-02-05T15_44_13_947Z-debug.log
```

**THIS IS THE LOG FOR THE "npm run export"**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'export'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.17.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'preexport', 'export', 'postexport' ]
5 info lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~preexport: 3dot@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~export: 3dot@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~export: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~export: PATH: /Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev/node_modules/.bin:/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin
9 verbose lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~export: CWD: /Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev
10 silly lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~export: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run build && next export -o _static' ]
11 silly lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~export: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle 3dot@0.1.0~export: Failed to exec export script
13 verbose stack Error: 3dot@0.1.0 export: `npm run build && next export -o _static`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid 3dot@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/baraa/Desktop/code_projects/3dotsdev
16 verbose Darwin 22.2.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/node" "/Users/baraa/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/npm" "run" "export"
18 verbose node v14.17.6
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error 3dot@0.1.0 export: `npm run build && next export -o _static`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the 3dot@0.1.0 export script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

---

**And this my Package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "3dot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3010",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "npm run build && next export -o _static"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.2",
    "next": "13.0.2",
    "next-translate": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.9",
    "tailwindcss-rtl": "^0.9.0",
    "taos": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^14.17.6",
    "npm": "~6.14.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

**If anyone have any Idea please tell me.**

Comment: why are you using npm version 1.0.20? from what I can see this  version does not exist https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm/v/1.0.20. Using a later version such as 1.4.29
might work

Comment: It was a wrong version of npm but I fix it to my latest version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.